# htaccess Restrict wordpress login by IP does not work

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

Im trying to restrict WordPress Login by IP but for any reason does not work the "allow from",

I have been restarted my server and seems do not work. any ideas?  (my IP is static). Always I get 403 error.

```
<Files wp-login.php>
Order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from MyIP
</Files>
```

Comment: Verify that the IP that the server sees, is actually the one you think it should. (Access log, PHP script outputting `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`, …)

Comment: @misorude WP show me a Private IP, why?

Comment: X-Forwarded-For . solved my problem, thank you @misorude

Answer (score 0):

What happened was that my WordPress was with a load balancer, and the IP shown was from the load balancer.

so I added a HTML Header (X-Forwarded-For) to fix it.

```
<Files wp-login.php>
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-For "myIP" env_allow_1
Allow from env=env_allow_1
</Files>
```